# The drive where Windows is installed is locked on Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, boot

Long story short I'm fairly certain our Windows 2012 server lost power while installing updates, and I've now spent the last 30 hours or so trying to get it fixed.

I'm pretty sure I've narrowed the issue down to the fact that the setting of the partitions and/or a corrupted BCD are to blame but so far, nothing I have found online has fixed it and nothing I have found explains clearly enough what needs to be done.

The sequence of issue is this:

1. Machine will not boot - there is simply an error message that the recovery disk needs to be used
2. When using recovery disk, automatic repair doesn't work (of course). After many hours of trying many things, I decided to try for a Refresh - however, there is an error message that `The drive where Windows is installed is locked. Unlock the drive and try again`.
3. Information online indicates there can be a few reason for this, and everything suggested is summed up at various points in this article:

https://neosmart.net/wiki/the-drive-where-windows-is-installed-is-locked/

4. Method 3 on that page (using chkdsk) returns no errors and no information.
5. Method 4 on that page (using bootrec) fails on the final command (`bootrec /RebuildBcd`) with the message `The requested system device cannot be found.`
6. Method 5 on that page *appears* to work OK, however, the machine still doesn't boot with the same issues and repair options still don't work.

I should point out that method 5 is unclear to me - for example one of the steps says to look for the partition using FAT32, but none of mine are as shown by my attached photos. Another issue is that the tutorial doesn't explain what each step is doing. Am I meant to copying things from the bootable USB? Am I copying from one volume to another? I can't tell what the goal is, so I don't know which drive letters I should be using at which times.

After this, I have tried running `sfc /scannow` as suggested below by snayob, but when I do this I get a message saying `There is a system repair pending which requires reboot to complete. Restart Windows and run sfc again.`Of course, I cannot restart Windows. When I reboot, I'm back to the beginning again.

I think what's not clear to me are the following questions:

1. Do I need to give each volume particular assigned letters? If so, what?
2. Related to that, the volume listed as C in the image wasn't called C when the machine was running - my main volume was called C, which has the OS installed on it (the one listed in diskpart as D). Similarly, the one listed in diskpart as E was previously called D.
3. Stupid question, but it's not 100% clear to me which volume is the system volume, though I think it's the one which is 350MB in size. Can anyone tell from the diskpart information?
4. Is this also the one I should be making "active"?
5. Overall, is it possible to tell exactly what I need to do here? I'm confident I'm close to getting it running again, but I've also tried everything I can find.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I've never had to get into this before so everything I know I've learnt in the last day or so.

**EDIT**

As per suggestions, I tried following the steps [here](http://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/The_drive_where_Windows_is_installed_is_locked.html). However, when running the command `sfc scannow`. I get the error:

```
There is a system repair pending which requires a reboot to complete. Restart Windows and run sfc again.
```

Of course, I can't do that. As per the article, I change this command to `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=d:\windows`. The output here is:

```
Resource Protection could not start the repair service.
```

So I run `net start trustedinstaller`. This command succeeds, but when I run the `sfc /scannow /offbootdir=c:\ /offwindir=d:\windows` command, I again get the message about not starting the repair service.

We've now spent a week on this - ridiculous. I was speaking with a friend who manages a huge number of servers and his suggestion as an answer was "Throw away all your Windows servers". He was half joking, but I think we are now at the stage where this is actually the answer - I'll give it another day or so then post that as a solution, because that's what we are going to have to do.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 30 Hours? Most people would have performed a bare metal recovery or would have rebuilt the server and restored relevant data by this point. Do you not have backups of/for this server?

Comment: We've got backups for the Jenkins installation we run on it, and I'm in the process now of trying to get a new install going using them - though it turns out they don't work very well, they do about half the job. My concern with a fresh install is that my Windows Server 2012 will then be unlicensed, if I understand correctly. It's also not mission critical though it does need to be fixed, and we were about to start using the server for AD so I need to get it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to completely rebuild the BCD. However, this alone didn't work, as noted earlier. I used the nuclear holocaust option described [here](https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/#Attempt_Three_Nuclear_Holocaust). However, I ran this multiple times and the machine still wouldn't boot. It was probably the fourth time I ran it, with minor variations, before I gave up. In this case, there was no error message, the Windows logo came up, then nothing. This had happened before so I didn't get too excited, though it did feel like progress. About six hours later the server started sending job failure notifications - it was running again.

For anyone having this issue, if you get the Windows logo but the machine still appears not to be booting, give it a few hours if you have the time and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

bootrec sometimes fails, but bcdboot could succeed in this case.

see [Fix - The drive where Windows is installed is locked](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/The_drive_where_Windows_is_installed_is_locked.html).

Comment: I had actually tried this as part one of the suggestions in the original link I posted. bcdboot appears to work fine and runs successfully. But when I switch the machine on, there is a message saying that Windows failed to start and to try the recovery disk. When I try this, the same issues arise when trying the various repair options.

Comment: Do you say that you followed the combination bcdboot + sfc to fix booting? if bcdboot succeeds boot files are OK, if sfc succeeds system files are OK, then try fixing drivers as next step.

Comment: I've edited the question to include this.

Comment: Your installation is MBR style - follow instructions for MBR booting. You have "System reserved" which is the partition with boot files. I think I could fix your booting in two minutes. Please read article in link given, you have to fix the chain of loaded files(group of files) on boot one after another.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any instructions for that in the link you provided?

Comment: What instructions? 1. chkdsk - to ensure disk is correct. 2. bcdboot - to ensure boot files are correct. 3. sfc - to ensure system files are correct? For drivers you obviously have to google to find out how to fix drivers. No one can put on a single web page all possible fixes for Windows!!!

Comment: You have to understand Windows boot sequence - read https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html

Answer (score 0):

Found this article on the MS technet blogs site. They call out another diskpart test you did not mention and thought it may help.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/06/02/my-disk-is-read-only-help/
Boot to recovery console etc on the affected system, then try the following:

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk # <where number is the OS install disk>
attributes disk
...text will say "current read only state = yes/no"
...if state = yes
attributes disk clear readonly
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but they were set to no on my machine.